# How connect a php script on docker container with network host, with a mysql docker container also on network host

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I have:

- apache+php docker container (net=host)
- mongo docker container (net=host)
- mysql docker container (net=host)

In the first container, A php script is dumping a database from mysql and migrating processed data to mongodb.
It write to mongodb, but a mysqldump command called from the script is not working.
This is the mysqldump command

```
mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u xxxxx -pxxxxxx
```

Got below error

```
 mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on
 '127.0.0.1' (111) when trying to connect
```

Note that this script is working on production without docker.
I tried to add:

```
--protocol=TCP
--port=3307
```

Also tried to change 127.0.0.1 to mysql ( container name ) but maybe it dont works with (net=host), but it still doesn't work.

If i do `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u xxxx -pxxxx` from the php container it works, but no from php script.

Commands i use to launch containers:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped --net=host --name mysql   -v /opt/mysql/mysql_config:/etc/mysql/conf.d -v /opt/mysql/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxx -d mysql:5.6

docker run --restart=unless-stopped --net=host --name apachephp -d apachephp
```

Comment: how you start contaner? and If `mysql` command like work then script should also work!

Comment: Hi, @Adiii i updated my question.

Comment: Why are you running all of these things on the host network?  That generally disables the Docker networking stack, and it's not necessary for typical TCP services like MySQL or an HTTP daemon.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is better to use [docker-compose networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). But providing a solution base on your current problem.

Using the Host network, the container does not get IP and linking does not work.

so the quick way to fix it can be remove `--net host` and add linking or you can create docker network as well.

You can publish port if you want to connect from host.

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped  --name mysql   -v /opt/mysql/mysql_config:/etc/mysql/conf.d -v /opt/mysql/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxx -d mysql:5.6

docker run --restart=unless-stopped --link mysql --name apachephp -d apachephp
```

Now you will be able to access MySQL using below command from PHP container.

```
mysql -h mysql -uroot -ppassword
```